# Sudden compilation errors within stdlib.h, math.h, stdio.h, string.h, stdarg.h, and many others

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've downloaded a source code originally from a Code::Blocks project, in which it works absolutely fine compiling with MinGW and GCC.
I tried to load it in Visual Studio 2010 and set the includes/libraries accordingly, but I'm getting tons and tons of errors from within the standard library headers and others as well.

Mainly, they are errors like:

> ...\stdlib.h(314): error C2146: syntax error : missing `')'` before identifier `'__nptr'`
>
> ...\stdlib.h(314): error C2061: syntax error : identifier `'__nptr'`
>
> ...\stdlib.h(314): error C2059: syntax error : `';'`
>
> ...\stdlib.h(314): error C2059: syntax error : `','`
>
> ...\stdlib.h(314): error C2059: syntax error : `')'`
>
> ...\stdlib.h(315): error C2373: `'__restrict__'` : redefinition; different type modifiers

From code:

`(314) strtod (const char* __restrict__ __nptr, char** __restrict__ __endptr);`
`(315) float __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strtof (const char * __restrict__, char ** __restrict__);`

And so on.

Must have screwed up big time to have such a massive amount of errors. I really have no idea where it went wrong though.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you set the includes and libraries "accordingly"?

Comment: More to the point, are you using MinGW's stdlib headers instead of the stdlib headers that comes with VS?

Comment: The original project requires additional libraries from tools like SDL and Lua. As I've downloaded the required files and added them in the C::B inclusion folders, I did the same with Visual Studio.
Also, this must sound pretty stupid... Is there a difference between the two files? (The answer would be yes to be honest)

Comment: I don't think those headers are compatible with Visual Studio.  You might want to check with the source.